# Downcasting UIImage to a UIImage subclass and calling method

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi so I  have a subclass of UIImage called SASUploadImage.

Here's SASUploadImage.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Device;

@interface SASUploadImage : UIImage

@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *timeStamp;

@end
```

Here's the .m

```
#import "SASUploadImage.h"

@implementation SASUploadImage

@synthesize timeStamp;

@end
```

So in another class I want to set the timeStamp property. I create a property called `sasUploadImage` and try get it to reference a `UIImage` object. Here's how I do it:

```
self.sasUploadImage = (SASUploadImage*)info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

`info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` <-- Returns a UIImage

Now I get that I can't just reference the `UIImage` object and call setTimeStamp. So that's why I tried to downcast it with `(SASUploadImage*)`

However, I get the following error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage setTimeStamp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170086180'`

I see why I have the error as its trying to called an unrecognised method, but now I'm not sure how I downcast the UIImage object so it is a SASUploadImage object. Is there any way I can make the UIImage object into a SASUploadImage object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way how type conversion works. info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] returns an instance of UIImage and you must not cast it to SASUploadImage because internally it is just the UIImage instance, not the SASUploadImage instance.
You can add custom initializer to the SASUploadImage class and create new instance with the image you have, for example:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Device;

@interface SASUploadImage : UIImage

@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *timeStamp;

- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)img;

@end
```

.m file

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)img {
    return [super initWithCGImage:[img CGImage]]
}
```

and then

```
UIImage *img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.sasUploadImage = [[SASUploadImage alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is fundamental OO behaviour. You cannot cast a UIImage to a UIImage subclass (or any object to a subclass of its class); only the opposite is allowed/possible. After all, subclassing usually adds specific logic to a class; the superclasses don't have that logic and therefor an object cannot be "treated" as being an instance of a subclass. While an *Apple* has all properties of a *Fruit*, an unspecified *Fruit* cannot be assumed to have all properties of an *Apple* (after all, it might be an Orange.)

If you have an `UIImage` and need a `SASUploadImage`, a solution would be add a class method that makes a `SASUploadImage` from an `UIImage`:

```
+ (SASUploadImage *)SASUploadImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage {
   SASUploadImage *result = [SASUploadImage new];
   NSData *imageData = [srcImage TIFFRepresentation]; // important - generates bitmap representation within image!
   NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
   NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
   imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:imageProps];

   SASUploadImage *result = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

   // additional code to copy the image's "content"
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I got confused on my inheritance rules there.